# Blockchain.info transactions missing in Ethereum wallet

Tags: transactions, ether, blockchain.info

I used blockchain.info to received  ETH when their Ethereum wallet was in beta. The transaction was on August 22 and 30, 2017. I was able to see the ETH in my account on their website back then, and the transaction for it also. I checked again a couple of times and it was still ok. But on October 27, when I checked again the ETH was gone. My account show 0 ETH, and no transactions also.

After some researching I noticed that the Ethereum address shown on their website is different from the address when I received the coin. I think they might have made some update that reset my private key and address.

I have sent lots a requests to support but they just keep telling me how to export my private key without answering if my key or address was changed or not. I tried to ask my question again but they haven't replied back for many days. They just stopped answering like this for almost a week once, I had to create a new requests to ask them to answer.

These transactions are lost in my wallet:

augustus 30: https://etherscan.io/tx/0xe230bed43032d667627ec999029b6b46030c643687bc5181ef318708f68158a4

augustus 22: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x7893bc6588d67a5c356997cc4430de736aaf597548004dd367038beae2aedc7b

I have seen an other users (like Duy Thai) having the same problem with blockchain.info. but his post was "put on hold" off topic...

Please contact me if you are facing these same problems with blockchain.info

Many thanks,

Comment: I am having the same issue. I tried to reach blockhain but no response yet. Please let me know if there is any solution to get ETHER back in wallet. Thanks
Usbukhari

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14878)

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "These transactions are lost in my wallet"? or "My account show 0 ETH, and no transactions also."

This address shows a balance of 0.69547237 ETH corresponding to the 2 transactions you list - of course because there are no transactions going out. All of this is visible here:
https://etherscan.io/address/0xeedbcbe0ef5455bee4ba417503ef17de8a62bdde

If you cannot see the correct balance on blockchain.info it may indeed be an issue with their wallet. Then just export your private key and use another wallet like https://www.myetherwallet.com/

CAUTION: be very careful when handling private keys and web wallet, always double check what you are doing

Comment: I do not see these transactions within the blockchain.info wallet. I have tried the export and import option to another wallet, no results. The Ethereum address shown on their website is different from the address when I received the coin. I think they might have made some update that reset my private key and address.

Comment: Your comment suggests that you have not imported the address 0xeedbcbe0ef5455bee4ba417503ef17de8a62bdde to the blockchain.info wallet, then obviously it will not display the transactions for this address. Import the address using the private key and everything will be fine. If you dont have the private key I am afraid there is nothing anyone can do.

Comment: The address (publick key) 0xeedbcbe0ef5455bee4ba417503ef17de8a62bdde has been generated by the blockchain.info wallet.

Comment: The (publickey) ETH address: 0xeedbcbe0ef5455bee4ba417503ef17de8a62bdde was generated (in aug) by the blockchain.info wallet. There is no option to import a public address back into in this wallet (makes sense i think). I did a complete recevery (12 word) in my wallet. Did not solve this problem. I think this public key does not pair with my private key (or they mixed up the private key in the wallet). During the transactions (aug) the wallet was in beta version (no option to export private key, only 12 word recovery). I do have the 12 word recovery key.

Comment: Let's make this short:
1) Is 0xeedbcbe0ef5455bee4ba417503ef17de8a62bdde listed as one of your address in Blockchain.info? If yes you should see all transactions and correct balance
2) If no, and you have the private key, just import the address to add the address
3) If it is not in Blockchain.info and you dont have the private, nothing anyone can do

Comment: 1>NO. not anymore, the have given me a new public (and  i think privatekey), during these transactions the gave me this address. 2>I have a private key (and 12 word seed), I do not see import options in blockchain.info wallet. I did the import option via myether wallet, but i did not get these two transactions. 3) blockchain wallet (beta) has given me a public key which does not pair with my privatekey. / wallet id.....

Comment: As per 2, when you import the private key in MEW, is the corresponding address 0xeedbcbe0ef5455bee4ba417503ef17de8a62bdde ? If yes, it should display the correct balance of 0.695ETH

Comment: tried to import in MEW, no results